# Are there any suggestions to read the 'Forgotten Realms' books?

Tags: suggested-order, forgotten-realms

A couple of months ago, I met with with Salvatore's fantasy world and I really loved it. At first I had no idea how big this world is. I've read 'The Dark Elf Trilogy' books (*Homeland*, *Exile* and *Sojourn*) and then when I checked online if there are any other publishings, I was just shocked.

As mentioned [here](https://www.alltimelines.com/forgotten-realms/), I see there are 273 novels and 188 short stories at least till 2016.

I'm so confused now, I don't know in which order I should read these books.

Should I continue with the chronological order? Is it worth it?

Are there any direct relations between any of the trilogies that I should consider to read first? For example; there are **A**,**B** and **C** trilogies given with the chronological order. The story in **C** starts just after the one ends in **A** and **B** is not relevant directly to the other two. So I would do better if I read **C** after **A**.

Any clue would be helpful.

Comment: Oh goodness... this one covers a really wide net. Are you only interested in Salvatore's work? Only particular regions and/or narratives?

Comment: I don't think you should follow any strict order, except within individual series/trilogies.  For instance you can read the Icewind Dale trilogy before reading the Dark Elf trilogy (this is what I did many years ago).  This doesn't spoil the Icewind Dale trilogy,as the Dark Elf trilogy helps set out some of Drizzt's back story of why a Drow is living on the surface

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Actually, I can't say anything about that. I don't know if other authors' works are good enough to read or if there are some relations between Salvatore's and some others' works to consider when reading.

Comment: @Alith thanks for the tip, but I've already read the Dark Elf trilogy. That's what I was afraid of, spoiling some stories

Comment: @Alith The Dark Elf Trilogy is a prequel to the Icewind Dale, written afterwards. The Drizzt character was created for the Icewind Dale setting,

Comment: Compiled several orders in an answer. Generally I prefer to stick to one author and read in their suggested order, then switch to another. Inconsistencies in books by different authors can make reading in strictly chronological order very confusing. Also, you may like one author but dislike another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Generally, you can check suggested order per author, as books by different authors generally should not spoil one another.**

If you prefer strictly chronoligical order, here is the [suggested compiled list](https://www.alltimelines.com/forgotten-realms/)

For *Robert Salvatore* books (Dark Elf, The Cleric Quintet) here is a suggested order:

## The Dark Elf series

There is already an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9430/chronological-order-of-the-drizzt-series) and [here (incomplete, but with some accompanying books)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/2emwsr/the_order_to_read_the_forgotten_realms_books/)

## The Cleric Quintet

- Canticle
- In Sylvan Shadows
- Night Masks
- The Fallen Fortress
- The Chaos Curse

## Elminster

*(By Ed Greenwood)* 
<sup>(found this in my e-reader, source unknown)</sup>

> 1. **Elminster Series** (Written after the Shandril saga, but starts with Elminster as a young boy)
>
>    - Making of a Mage (212 - 241 DR)
>    - Elminster in Myth Drannor (241 - 261 DR)
>    - Temptation of Elminster (759 - 767)
> 2. **Elminster at the Magefair**, short story (1355 DR)
> 3. **Shandril Saga** (Some chronologies suggest reading it first, probably because it was written first. Elminster is not a main character, secondary characters appearing in other books are introduced)
>
>    - Spellfire (1356 - 1357 DR)
>    - Crown of Fire (1357 DR)
>    - Hand of Fire (1357 DR)
> 4. **Shadows of the Avatar trilogy** (It takes place during in the Time of Troubles simoultaneously with the Avatar series, by other writers, which also includes an Elminster cameo. I read the Avatar series first, but can't say if it would be better the other way around).
>
>    - Shadows of doom (1358 DR)
>    - Cloak of shadows (1358 DR)
>    - All shadows fled (1358 DR)
> 5. **Elminster in Hell** (1372 DR, stand alone book)
> 6. **Elminsters Daughter** (1373 DR, stand alone)
> 7. **The Sage of Shadowdale series**
>
>    - Elminster Must Die! (1479 DR - The year of the ageless one, as stated in the book itself))
>    - Bury Elminster Deep (1479 DR)
>    - Elminster Enraged (1479 DR)
> 8. **The Herald**.
>      The Herald is the last book of the The Sundering series. Some reviewers say it may be comfusing if one has not read the rest of the Sundering books, and I intend to do so. This means reading a lot of other older novels as well. If I get up to speed by the end of the summer I will post accordingly.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a chronological order and I know there could be more than one answer to my question. I think **check suggested order per author** is the key phrase in your answer and that's what I am planning to do.

Answer (score 2):

For the Salvatore books, "The Cleric Quintet" should be read prior to the "Paths of Darkness" series.  There are some connections between the Drizzt storylines and the "Cleric" characters after that point.

You don't *need* to do so, but being up-to-date on both storylines before they touch each other may make a better reading experience.

Comment: Hmm...   I had meant this to be a comment on TimSparrow's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll keep this in my mind.

Comment: I readf the Cleric Quintet after Transitions. Although there are connections, nothing major is spoiled. It can be well read as a prequel or a spin-off, as the Jarlaxle/Entreri trilogy.

Answer (score 1):

Paul S. Kemp's Erevis Cale books. Shadow's Witness is the first and part of the Sembia Series. Then he wrote the Erevis Cale trilogy, followed by the Twilight War trilogy, the last book was Godborn.